# TypeScript allow any class that extends another class in arguments

Tags: typescript, decorator

```
class BaseRouter {
    protected $decoratedRoutes[];
}

@SomeDecorator
class APIRouter extends BaseRouter {}


function SomeDecorator <ExtendedRouter extends BaseRouter>(extendingClass: ExtendedRouter) {}


error TS2345:
src/Server/Routes/Api/V1/System/index.ts(7,2): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof APIRouter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseRouter'.
Property '$decoratedRoutes' is missing in type 'typeof ApiRouter'.
```

The interface that I made in `<ExtendedRouter extends BaseRouter>` is just a wild guess from browsing a couple of examples. How do I correctly allow any class to be passed that extends `BaseRouter` inside the decorator? The code is of course working fine, I just have 70+ of this error since switching to a decorator-pattern in my express.js app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more fiddling and research, I found this to be working the best:

```
class BaseRouter {
    protected $decoratedRoutes[];
}

@SomeDecorator
class APIRouter extends BaseRouter {}


function SomeDecorator <ExtendedRouter extends BaseRouter<any>>(extendingClass: ExtendedRouter) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the classes are polymorphic, you can just specify `BaseRouter` and sub-class (and classes that derive from them) are all acceptable...

```
class BaseRouter {
    protected example: string;
}

@SomeDecorator
class APIRouter extends BaseRouter { }

@SomeDecorator
class AnotherRouter extends APIRouter { }


function SomeDecorator<BaseRouter>(extendingClass: BaseRouter) {

}
```

Comment: when I call `let extClass = new extendingClass();` I get the error `Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.` I need to construct `extendingClass` and do some changes before returning it from the decorator

Comment: After some more fiddling, I found this to be working `<T extends BaseRouter<any>>(extendingClass: T)`.